# Is it possible for a file to refer to it's own IPFS hash?

Tags: ipfs

If we're talking about HTTP URL it's possible for a resource to have a reference to it's own URL. Is such a thing possible in IPFS?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the IPFS hash is based on its content, it *might* be possible but it would be very very difficult to do.

This is one of the things IPNS solves.